# How does espresso time idler behave?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using above technique mentioned in the [blog](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/06/espresso-elapsed-time.html) , however I have noticed that it doesn't wait for required 15 seconds that I am trying to set. My question here, if all the backend task is completed before 15 seconds, does espresso identifies it and starts the next consecutive operations? Any leads on this is appreciated.

```
    public class ElapsedTimeIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
  private final long startTime;
  private final long waitingTime;
  private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

  public ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(long waitingTime) {
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return ElapsedTimeIdlingResource.class.getName() + ":" + waitingTime;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isIdleNow() {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    boolean idle = (elapsed >= waitingTime);
    if (idle) {
      resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
    return idle;
  }

  @Override
  public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(
      ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
  }
    }

==

long waitingTime = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS / 4;

IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(
    waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(
    waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

IdlingResource idlingResource 
    = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime);
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);
```

Comment: I suspect that is what's happening, but could you post your relevant code here so we can confirm it?

Comment: I cannot post the code, it is on corporate account. But I have used the approach mentioned in the blog below. [link] http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/06/espresso-elapsed-time.html

Comment: I meant the code you're using in your own app, unless you've directly copied the code in that blog but changed the timeout to 15 seconds?

Comment: Ok, if the code can't be shared that's fair enough, but it'll make our job harder to help you. I'll run a couple of spikes to see if I can confirm this. From what I can see, if your `isIdleNow()` method is dependent on if your process is running, then yes, the test will continue as soon as Espresso detects that `isIdleNow()` returns `true`.

Comment: Michael, thank you much for stepping forward to help me. I have updated the post.

Comment: When you say `it doesn't wait for required 15 seconds that I am trying to set`, I'm guessing you mean less than 15 seconds rather than more?

Comment: I have set 2 15 seconds wait time before performing 2 test steps. So I expect the entire test case to take 2* 15 seconds(Idlers time) + time required for executing the test steps.

Comment: That's what I'm clarifying, the tests take a shorter time than expected?

Comment: yes. takes shorter than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run an Espresso command, any Espresso command, following `registerIdlingResources()`. I've created this example unit test on my own PC and it works fine.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Rule public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    private final long waitingTime = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS / 4;

    @Before public void setUp() {
        IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Test public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime);

        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);
        onView(withId(R.id.btnStart)).perform(click());
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);

        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Test results]

In my example, I have a button called `btnStart` that I perform a click on, but it can be anything relevant to your app. Let me know if that works for you.

---

And to directly answer your further questions in the comments:

1. `isIdleNow()` is constantly polled by Espresso after an Idling resource is registered. When `idle` is `true`, that's the signal for Espresso to *proceed to the next command*. You need `isIdleNow()` to return `false` if you want to block.
2. In this specific case, no, the Idling Resource is purely based on time, not the state of a background process, but you *can* make Idling Resources that poll the state of running threads/processes. Unless your process ends by closing the activity, Espresso will wait, but will only block **itself** (e.g. stuff like `ViewMatchers`, clicks, etc), not any other threads. The activity will continue to function as normal.

Comment: Does it wait for 15 seconds and then perform a button click? Are there any background operations that is being performed after .registerIdlingResrouces(idlingResource)

Comment: Yes. The button is clicked after the Idling resource has waited for 15 seconds. Any background operations that begin before `registerIdlingResrouces()` will continue to run while Espresso is waiting (i.e. Espresso only blocks itself). Ideally, you should be checking for your result after `registerIdlingResrouces()` e.g. a `TextView` contains the text you expect.

Comment: I am adding wait time at 2 places, 15 seconds each. My observation is the wait time is not complete 15 seconds. After all the items in list view loads 1) isIdleNow is called even after idle=true; 2) the espresso commands after registerIdlingResources gets executed. These behavior brings back to my actual question -  if all the backend task is completed before 15 seconds, does espresso identifies it and starts the next consecutive operations? Based on our observation, espresso identifies and starts running next commands after all background operation completes.

Comment: Again, it will be difficult to answer your question without specific code examples from your JUnit Test class. Are you calling `registerIdlingResources` within a `@test` method? By `two separate places` do you mean two separate `@test` methods or twice within one test? Do you have an activity `@rule` in place at the top of your test class?